# Retrieving shared video memory using SharpDX

Tags: directx, sharpdx

I am trying to retrieve the total available video memory using SharpDX via DXGI, using the Description of the best available adapter.

The DedicatedVideoMemory is correct (1GB in my case), but the SharedSystemMemory value is wrong - and in fact is a negative number (-1073549312, in case that's of interest). The correct value should be 3072MB, as reported by my system information and when running the Microsoft VideoMemory_2012 example application (which also queries DXGI).

Any ideas what might be going on? Or is there another way to get this information using SharpDX? I need to scale some textures according to the available resources, and I need to know the shared component as well as the dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when my App was 32 bit.
Try 64 bit and see if the number is correct then...